# Why does Django ORM require all() for filter() but not for order_by()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In Django ORM why does order_by() does not require all() while filter() do? Example,

```
Mymodel.objects.order_by('param')
Mymodel.objects.all().filter('param')
```

Comment: It does not require "all()" for filter. You can directly do Mymodel.objects.filter()

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get queryset with missed all() also.

**Try**:

`Mymodel.objects.filter('param')`

**Link to documentation**:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters